# WinForm DataGridView delete little expand triangle

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a Windows Form that shows some data in a DataGridView.
I don't like this little triangle here in the image below (in the red circle).

[image]

How can I hide it so I just see the data and I save space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible =false;
```

Comment: This isn't good if you have a value in the Row Header, all will disappear.